# Joda bounding dates for partial date

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I'm working on a java component that tags events with a date window for aggregating metrics by day, week, month, and so forth.

Mapping from a date to its aggregate category is straightforward - just format as a `String` using an appropriate pattern for the desired window.  For example, a date could be mapped to month-level aggregation with the [`Formatter` pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) `"%1$04tY-%1$02tm"` (i.e., *`YYYY-MM`*).

My problem is reverse-mapping from the window to its bounding dates, e.g. from the aggregate month `2012-02` to its bounding dates `2012-02-01` and `2012-03-01` (using half-open intervals).  I need this to effectively tag entire spans of dates in my data store (MongoDB) with a single statement (this example omits `ISODate(…)` for clarity):

```
db['events'].update( 
    {eventDate: {$gte: "2012-02-01", $lt: "2012-03-01"}, 
    {$set: {month: "2012-02"}
);
```

I came across [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) and suspect that its [`Partial`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_partial.html) API might support this functionality.  I'm trying to teach myself, but does anyone already know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joda-Time is definitely the way to go for this.

Depending on what you want to do with TimeZones, the following shows what I think you want.

```
    YearMonth ym = new YearMonth(2012, DateTimeConstants.MARCH);
    Interval interval = ym.toInterval();
    LocalDate monthStart = interval.getStart().toLocalDate();
    LocalDate monthEnd = interval.getEnd().toLocalDate();

    System.out.println("Start:" + monthStart);
    System.out.println("End: " + monthEnd);
```

*Note: This requires at least Joda-Time v2.0*

Comment: the missing piece is parsing a Partial from a String, but i'm gathering that this is not yet implemented in Joda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068626

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html

You can construct the lower bound by parsing the year and the month from the window,
and then

`LocalDate lowerBound = new LocalDate(year, month, 1)`

Then, the upper bound is

```
LocalDate upperBound = lowerBound.plusMonths(1)
```