# Joda-time: parse String with optional fields into a ReadablePartial of only the fields that are present

Tags: datetime, jodatime

I have a requirement to parse a date (and/or time) with some optional parts and also discover what fields are specified.

Joda-time has a wonderful [Partial](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Partial.html) type and many sister types that can represent the expected result perfectly.

However, the [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class requires you to know what fields are present (i.e. you have to choose between parseLocalDate, parseLocalDateTime, etc.

So is there anyway to parse a `Partial`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Joda-Time Partials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068626/parsing-joda-time-partials)